# How to make a horizontal scrolling strip with divs partly out of viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a div with 4 or 5 other divs in it and I want to be able to horizontally scroll/swipe the divs.

[image]

I've tried some of the things I could find here on StackOverflow, but nothing provided me with what I intend to do. I also don't really know what to look for (name of scripts) so that makes it extra difficult.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: visit my site https://nisharg.me/travel, where i do like that using bootstrap. if you dont want to use bootstrap, slick js is the best option

Comment: I would recommend posting the code that you have tried. And technically what you are looking for are called `carousels`.

Comment: @NishargShah I've checked your site and that is exactly what I mean. I am using bootstrap already, but do you use any javascript for this?

Comment: yes i used js for this, let me give you code of it

Answer (score 1):

```css
.outerDiv {
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.innerDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="innerDiv"></div>
  <div class="innerDiv"></div>
  <div class="innerDiv"></div>
  <div class="innerDiv"></div>
  <div class="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried multiple things (the answers above and other carousel libraries) and I ended up using OwlCarousel. https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do things like this. You force browser to render something which is not shown to the user anyway. Also it might be tricky to handle this with different aspect ratio on screens like 21:9, 32:9 etc.

I would rather suggest you to use something like carousel (e.g. with Materialize https://materializecss.com/carousel.html)

If you really want to do it like this, you can try messing with css properties `position: absolute;` and  `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

Here the snippet that you want

```js
$('#recipeCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    
    for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
      next=next.next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(33.33333%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-33.33333%);
}
  
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
  transform: translateX(0);
}
</style>

<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=2">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=3">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=4">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=5">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block col-4 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=6">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Scripts are here -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks you, Nishang. I tried this but it didn't work for me. I ended up using OwlCarousel.

Comment: ok but don't forgot to consider up-vote and check this answer as best answer for you by clicking on right arrow, thanks!